# declare extern "C" with different return values

Tags: c++, assembly, return-value, extern

I have an function called *ecall* defined in external ASM file. This function takes different count of arguments and return different values.

This is how it looks like in my source code:

```
int ret = _function1("Hello", "world");
HANDLER h = _function2(123456);
char * ch = _function3("asdf", 789, h);
// ... and so on
```

These "functions" are actually macros generated with a simple python script. This auto-generated header file where all these macros are defined looks like:

```
extern "C" ????? ecall(int code, ...);

#define _function1(...) ecall(0x123, __VA_ARGS__)
#define _function2(...) ecall(0x234, __VA_ARGS__)
#define _function3(...) ecall(0x345, __VA_ARGS__)
#define _function4(...) ecall(0xABC, __VA_ARGS__)
// ... and around 500 more definitions with a different code value
```

However, I am stuck on the declaration of the *ecall* (I've marked as "?????"). I need to somehow specify return values, but in fact this function returns pretty much everything (depending on *int code* value) -- booleans, integers, pointers, etc.

Is there a way how to do this? I am compiling on MSVC10.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the answer to life the universe and everything? `void *`

Comment: You'd be well advised to avoid names beginning with underscore; they are reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: Why are you hiding 500 different functions behind a single assembler function?  Why don't you use 500 different functions?

Comment: Does ecall have some giant `switch (code) {/* case 0x123... */}` in it?  If so, what is the advantage of this over simply creating multiple functions with types clearly declared?

Comment: @dgnorton No, it's just a small piece of ASM code which I am using as an intermediate layer to obfuscate and hide different API calls. It works perfectly when I explicitly declare return values, however I need to generate these defines automatically and my python code doesn't know what types will be returned for specific function.

Comment: @H2CO3 I've already tried `void *`, but it just returned a lot of C2446 and C2040 compiler errors. Can I somehow force my compiler to turn off these errors?

Comment: @user1558605 How is this going to obfuscate the .exe?  Seems more of a source obfuscation.  MSVC doesn't put symbol names in .exe's.  If the API is in a static lib you should be fine.  If the API is in a DLL (does it really have to be??) "func1", "func2", etc. should be fine.

Comment: C++ has some pretensions towards being strictly typed; you are trying to buck the conventions of strict typing.  It is hard work fighting the language; the standard advice is "Don't".  If your program is popular enough to be worth ripping off, the obfuscation you're introducing won't protect you from those determined to do so.  If your program is not popular enough, then the effort is wasted.  Either way, all you're doing is making your own life harder for minimal (to negative) benefit.  I suggest not bothering.

Answer (score 2):

Either create your own variant type (a union with each type included), or as I would more strongly suggest, create different functions that each return only one specific type.

Comment: As I said, this header file is auto-generated, that python script don't know what type will be returned. This ASM function is used as an intermediate layer for API calls from external libraries, so I can't change their return value to only one specific type.

Comment: Do you have control over the source of the python script? Or the .asm source? If so, I don't see why you can't change up things to make the "glue" typesafe.

Comment: I have for example: `while(function1(event, 1000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)`. How can a python script find out what is a return type of a `function1`?

Comment: I've no idea how you are generating your macros.. is it actually parsing and analyzing the code that uses the ASM function?

Comment: Exactly, my python script parse all relevant function in the project and redefine them as a macro in auto-generated header file. The only problem is how to declare that ASM function in C++.

Comment: Well, since you are using C++, you are not going to get away with doing this without at least modifying the call sites.. either casting the `void *` to what the caller is expecting or doing the variant type suggested in my answer (but then the caller pulls out the correct field in the union).